# Total number of voters in the primaries?

Tags: feature-request, election

We can obviously see exactly what votes have been cast in the primaries, but given each user can cast between 0 and [num candidates] votes we can't tell how many users have actually voted so far.

I understand from the blog that the full vote list for the final election will be released after the elections, but I wonder if the same is planned for the primaries?

Essentially, I'm interesting in how many users have cast at least one vote (preferably before they finish, to go along with the current vote counts).

It's not vital, but could be interesting - if the top candidate has 300 votes from 300 voters that's potentially got very different meaning from the case where the top candidate has 300 votes from 1500 voters...

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is interesting, but I don't think there is much of a use for it.  If there were 1500 voters and one candidate got 300 votes and another got 50.  Nothing really changes if the total number of voters was 2000 instead.